# Making an clickable particle system using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making my first steps learning to code and playing with three.js. Since some time ago I've been looking for a way to make interactive geometries in three.js. So I find this (it doesn't open the links in the snippet I don't know why, but it works):

```js
  var container, stats;
  var camera, scene, projector, renderer;
  var particleMaterial;
  var objects = [];
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
      container = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(container);
      
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
      camera.position.set(0, 300, 500);
    
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      
      var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
      
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
             color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
             opacity: 0.5
         }));
         
         object.position.x = i;
         object.position.y = i * 10 + i * 100;
         object.position.z = i;
         scene.add(object);
        
         switch (i) {
             case 0:
                 object.userData = {
                     URL: "http://google.com"
                 };
                break;
            
             case 1:
                 object.userData = {
                    URL: "http://yahoo.com"
                };
                break;

             case 2:
                 object.userData = {
                    URL: "http://msn.com"
                };
                break;
            
             case 3:
                 object.userData = {
                    URL: "http://engadget.com"
                };
                break;

             case 4:
                 object.userData = {
                    URL: "http://stackoverflow.com"
                };
                break;
        }

        scene.add(object);
        objects.push(object);
    }

    projector = new THREE.Projector();
    
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0xfffff, 0);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
   
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    //
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 }


function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
    
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
    
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
    }
}

function animate() {
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
   
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
  <style>
   body {
    font-family: Monospace;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
```

Then I wanted to continue experimenting and make it harder. So I wanted to make this but instead using cubes, using particles. I am stetically inspired from this Three.js demo:

```js
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0,

   windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
   windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,

   SEPARATION = 200,
   AMOUNTX = 10,
   AMOUNTY = 10,

   camera, scene, renderer;

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    var container, separation = 100, amountX = 50, amountY = 50,
    particles, particle;

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 100;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // particles

    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

     color: 0xffffff,
     program: function ( context ) {

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
      context.fill();

     }

    } );

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) {

     particle = new THREE.Sprite( material );
     particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
     particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
     particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
     particle.position.normalize();
     particle.position.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 10 + 450 );
     particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 10;
     scene.add( particle );

     geometry.vertices.push( particle.position );

    }

    // lines

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 } ) );
    scene.add( line );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

   }

   function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   //

   function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

   }

   function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

    if ( event.touches.length > 1 ) {

     event.preventDefault();

     mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
     mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

    }

   }

   function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

    if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

     event.preventDefault();

     mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
     mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

    }

   }

   //

   function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

   }

   function render() {

    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY + 200 - camera.position.y ) * .05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
```

So I decided to use that demo to make each spherical vertice in a clickable element. In a link.

I've been trying this since a week ago but I can't find a solution and my best approach is this:

```js
   var container;
   var camera, scene, renderer;

   var raycaster;
   var mouse;

   var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;

   var programStroke = function ( context ) {

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
    context.fill();

   };

   var programFill = function ( context ) {

    context.lineWidth = 0.025;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
    context.stroke();

   };

   var INTERSECTED;

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 300, 500 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    for ( var i = 0; i < 200; i ++ ) {

     var particle = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0x000fff , program: programStroke } ) );
     particle.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
     particle.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
     particle.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
     particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
     particle.data = { url: "http://google.com" }
     scene.add( particle );

    }
    
    
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
     document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

   }

   function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

   }

   //

   function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

   }

   function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    
    
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

     window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");

     INTERSECTED = null;

    }
    
   }

   var radius = 600;
   var theta = 0;

   function render() {

    // rotate camera

    theta += 0.1;

    camera.position.x = radius * Math.sin( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
    camera.position.y = radius * Math.sin( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
    camera.position.z = radius * Math.cos( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    camera.updateMatrixWorld();

    // find intersections

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );



    renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
```

This is not exactly as I want but at least it is a clickable particle. But how can I do to use randomly several links when I click the particles?

I found this example in the three.js library http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_particles there is an interaction but no as I want it. I tryied to modify the element to be clickable but I didn't find a solution.

Do you have a suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See this answer - [three.js click single particle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308105/three-js-click-single-particle)

The key point is attaching all of the particles to a particle array so they can be raycasted later.

The attached fiddle has an example for how to change the material on particle interaction.